# webpshere profile restore command

Tags: websphere

I'm looking to restore a backed up profile to a new profile for WAS.

I'm currently using this command :

> C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\restoreConfig
>   ProfilDGR_SA.car -username userwas -password userwas -profileName
>   PROFIL_DGR -force

But it seems something is wrong because I get the following message :

> ADMU5502I: The directory C:\Program
>   Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\PROFILDGR\config already
>   exists; renaming to C:\Program
>              Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\PROFILDGR\config.old ADMU5503E: The restore location could not be renamed - another process
>   may be using this subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

The tech note below is for WebSphere portal but root cause is in profile restoration and matches your case.

> This issue can be caused by any file-indexing service (such as Google Desktop) running on the system, or Norton Antivirus.
>
> To resolve this problem you must do the following:
>
> ...
>
> - Temporarily disable all antivirus and file indexing services.

Also make sure your servers depending on that profile are not running.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=688&context=SSHRKX&context=SS3JLV&context=SS3NNG&context=SSYJ99&context=SSRUWN&context=SS6JVW&q1=1390990&uid=swg21390990&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en

Comment: I simply rebooted my PC and was able to do the restore. I do not have Norton Anti-Virus nor do I have Google Desktop.

Comment: Nice to hear. So whatever process locking the folder was gone. This is the same problem as when Windows tells you it can't delete a folder because it's currently in use.